# Umbraco Backend Member information

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, umbraco7, members

I have created members in umbraco, which can login (frontend), to a user area.

I have also under members in umbraco, created fields, with information like profile picture, address, phone etc. which i can set in the backend of umbraco.

But i would also like to display that information in the user area, which the member logs into.

but i haven't been able to find a way, to get that information out.

i can use `membership.getuser()`, to get the current user logged in.

But how do i get the information set in backend ?

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
//first, get the member
var member = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.MemberService
            .GetByUsername(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
```

The properties of the member are now available in the `Properties` collection -

```
var properties = member.Properties;
```

This is a `PropertyCollection` object, which is a `KeyedCollection` - and ultimately can be iterated over, or searched.